# Magento 2.3 admin login not working-cleared cache and different browsers

Tags: admin, login, magento2.3

I have an install of Magento 2.3 with the pearl theme installed. It's on a light sail instance (Ubuntu). I was changing some settings (the bug with not being able to upload logos) and then when I cleared my cache to look at my changes I could no longer log in on the admin panel. I re-cleared my cache, and tried a different browser but still wasn't able to get in. The session and cookies haven't been changed from the install, and I do have SSH/SFTP access if I need to change something there. What should I do next to get back in to my admin side?

Edit from comments:

Not able to login = login page redirects to login in page on correct login, or on wrong login will post "incorrect login"

No error is showing in any logs I have seen

Comment: please elaborate "not able to log in" do you not see the login form? do you get a message?

Comment: What error is coming if you try to login in admin.

Comment: edited question for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html .

Try unlocking your user in case if it is locked or you can simply create a new admin user via command line as explained in above reference. Let me know if any issue further.

Comment: I will try this and let you know! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Hey, so I was able to make a new account and login, thanks. I have another question however, the first admin account wasn't locked but I'm still not able to get in. Any other ideas that might affect this?